# Function to find Armstrong numbers in a given range fails at some point

Tags: c++

The assignment was to build a function to check if numbers in a range are armstrong numbers, and to add them in a vector. There are some problems when I call main, it won't execute the for loop part. I kinda think that the function is alright, because when I just call the function, there are no errors. The code is below, and I hope that you can help me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

std::vector<int> ArmstrongoviBrojevi (int , int );

std::vector<int> ArmstrongoviBrojevi (int p, int q) {
    //function start
    int z=0;
    if (p<0){
        std::vector<int> dodajVrijednost;    
        for (int i=1;i<=q;i++){
            std :: string a = std:: to_string(i);
            //check for length 
            int duzina = a.length();
            int sum=0;
            //check if number if armstrong
            while (i>0){
                int cifra=i%10;
                i/=10;
                sum+=pow(cifra,duzina);

            }
            //add to the vector
            if (sum==i){


                dodajVrijednost[z];
                z++;

            }

            return dodajVrijednost;

        }
    }
}

//main
int main() {
    std::cout << "Zadaća 1, Zadatak 1";

    int a,b;
    std::cout << "Molim vas unesite 2 broja" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a>>b;
    std::vector<int>kopija ;

    for (int g=0;g<ArmstrongoviBrojevi(a,b).size();g++){
        if (g!=int(ArmstrongoviBrojevi(a,b).size())-1){
        std::cout << ArmstrongoviBrojevi(a,b)[g] <<","<< std::endl;
        }
        else
        std::cout << ArmstrongoviBrojevi(a,b)[g] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two error in the `ArmstrongoviBrojevi` function. I guess the main one is that when condition `p < 0` return false you don't return any value, but in `main` still trying to access it. To fix it you could declare `dodajVrijednost` outside of the `if` block and return value after it

```
std::vector<int> dodajVrijednost;
if (p < 0) {
    ...
}
return dodajVrijednost;
```

Another one is that `dodajVrijednost[z];` should be `dodajVrijednost.push_back(z);`. Because you don't allocate memory for the vector somewhere before there is no element on index `z`. And statement `dodajVrijednost[z];` alone does not make any sense.

I would also modify the `main` function, because now you recalculate your vector each time, it would be better to calculate result once.

```
std::vector<int> armstrongoviBrojevi = ArmstrongoviBrojevi(a,b);
for (int g=0;g<armstrongoviBrojevi.size();g++){
    if (g!=armstrongoviBrojevi.size()-1){
    std::cout << armstrongoviBrojevi[g] <<","<< std::endl;
    }
    else
    std::cout << armstrongoviBrojevi[g] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/* Java program to find Armstrong numbers in a range */

```
class  A{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int starting_number = 1;
        int ending_number = 99999;
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = starting_number; i <= ending_number; i++) {
            if (isArmstrong(i)) {
                c++;
                if(c==1)
                {
                System.out.print(i);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(", "+i);
                }
            } else {
                
            }
        }
    }
 
    public static boolean isArmstrong(int n) {
        int no_of_digits = String.valueOf(n).length();
        int sum = 0,s=0;
        int value = n;
        for (int i = 1; i <= no_of_digits; i++) {
            int digit = value % 10;
            value = value / 10;
            sum = sum + (int) Math.pow(digit, no_of_digits);
        }
        if (sum == n) {  
            s=s+sum;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I want sum of it